# Python regex to find substring

Tags: python, regex

Sample text

```
port0 interface GigabitEthernet0/4/0

port1 interface TenGigabitEthernet0/1/0

login delay 2

bfd-template single-hop BDI

ip ftp source-interface Loopback0

ip tftp source-interface Loopback0

interface Loopback0

interface Loopback100

interface Loopback999

description *** Loopback interface for management ***

interface TenGigabitEthernet0/0/0

mtu 9216

carrier-delay msec 0

interface TenGigabitEthernet0/1/0

mtu 9216

carrier-delay msec 0

interface GigabitEthernet0/4/0

mtu 9216

interface GigabitEthernet0/4/1
```

my regex is

```
[T][e]((?:.|\n)*?[e][c]\s\d+)
```

and im verifying it at pythex.org

it matches the below –

```
TenGigabitEthernet0/1/0

mtu 9216

carrier-delay msec 0
```

Which is what I want. But it also matches –

```
TenGigabitEthernet0/1/0

login delay 2

bfd-template single-hop BDI

ip ftp source-interface Loopback0

ip tftp source-interface Loopback0

interface Loopback0

interface Loopback100

interface Loopback999

description *** Loopback interface for management ***

interface TenGigabitEthernet0/0/0

mtu 9216

carrier-delay msec 0
```

Which I don’t want. I am looking for a `multiline regex` which exactly matches only all the `tengig-mtu-carrier-delay part(s)` in my string.

What I have written is -

```
buffer_=open(file,"rb")
sb=buffer_.read().replace('\r\r\n','')
inf = re.compile(r'[T][e]((?:.|\n)*?[e][c]\s\d+)')
intf = inf.findall(sb)
print intf
buffer_.close()
```

and it works perfectly for files which have the `tengig-mtu-carrier-delay` in sequential lines, but not so perfectly. If there is any `tengig` also found elsewhere?

Comment: Can you highlight what you've tried? SO is a place for problems during programming, not for writing a regex for you.

Comment: why don't you match the exact string if you know what you want to match?

Comment: Thanks Alexander- i have also pasted my code and researching for the correct regex will also post the answer if i get it.

Comment: Ahsanul -> no i cant match the exact string because there could be more than one instance of the tengig interface.

Comment: what do you want to match exactly?

Comment: rock-> i want match all instances like below exactly-           TenGigabitEthernet0/1/0

mtu 9216

carrier-delay msec 0

Comment: like **[this](https://regex101.com/r/nK7qY6/1)**

Comment: thanks rock!! looks good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this regex is what you want

```
(tengig.*?(?:\n+)?\bmtu\b.*?(?:\n+)?\bcarrier-delay\b[^\n]+)
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nK7qY6/2)**

*Regex Breakdown*

```
( #Capturing group
 tengig #Match tengig literally
 .*? #Lazy matching to meet next next requirement
 (?:\n+)? #Match next \n (OPTIONAL)
 \bmtu\b #Match mtu literally
 .*? #Lazy matching to meet next requirement
 (?:\n+)? #Match next \n (OPTIONAL)
 \bcarrier-delay\b #Match carrier-delay literally
 [^\n]+ #Match anything till a new line 
) #End capturing group
```

*Python Code*

```
p = re.compile(r'(tengig.*?(?:\n+)?\bmtu\b.*?(?:\n+)?\bcarrier-delay\b[^\n]+)', re.MULTILINE | re.IGNORECASE)
test_str = "port0 interface GigabitEthernet0/4/0\n\nport1 interface TenGigabitEthernet0/1/0\n\nlogin delay 2\n\nbfd-template single-hop BDI\n\nip ftp source-interface Loopback0\n\nip tftp source-interface Loopback0\n\ninterface Loopback0\n\ninterface Loopback100\n\ninterface Loopback999\n\ndescription * Loopback interface for management *\n\ninterface TenGigabitEthernet0/0/0\n\nmtu 9216\n\ncarrier-delay msec 0\n\ninterface TenGigabitEthernet0/1/0\n\nmtu 9216\n\ncarrier-delay msec 0\n\ninterface GigabitEthernet0/4/0\n\nmtu 9216\n\ninterface GigabitEthernet0/4/1\n"
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/tuPFoz)**

Comment: this works fine and what i wanted , but - not working when i read the file having the text_str into a buffer and then try to print the re.findall          inf = re.compile(r'(tengig.*?(?:\n+)?\bmtu\b.*?(?:\n+)?\bcarrier-delay\b[^\n]+)', re.MULTILINE | re.IGNORECASE)
 buffer_=open(file,"rb").read()
 print(re.findall(inf,buffer_))                                                             output is just [] for each file iterated   
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]

Comment: @user6259926 its working fine for me..for a single file i am using **[this](http://ideone.com/7mtY7a)** code

Comment: yes i read the entire file in one go.                                                            for file in os.listdir(currdir):                                                                         inf = re.compile(ur'(tengig.*?(?:\n+)?\bmtu\b.*?(?:\n+)?\bcarrier-delay\b[^\n]+)', re.MULTILINE | re.IGNORECASE)
 
 buffer_=open(file,"rb").read()
 intf=(re.findall(inf,buffer_))                                                                                print intf

Comment: @user6259926 i have added the code for a single file..try it with single file then update me

Comment: im down to a single file and no loop. but doesnt print.                    import sys
import re
import os
currdir = "."
inf = re.compile(ur'(tengig.*?(?:\n+)?\bmtu\b.*?(?:\n+)?\bcarrier-delay\b[^\n]+)', re.MULTILINE | re.IGNORECASE)
buffer_=open('test.txt',"rb").read()
intf=(re.findall(inf,buffer_))
print intf
 
-----o/p----
 []
suspicion points to either name or size of the file.

Comment: finally got some output by doing buffer_=open('test.txt',"rb").read().replace('\r\r\n','')

Comment: @user6259926 are you using windows??

Comment: @user6259926 instead of using replace, try using **[this](https://regex101.com/r/nK7qY6/3)** regex and update me

Comment: @user6259926 that's why there was problem..did you tried another regex I gave without replacement?

Comment: yes even the regex you gave last and without replace just emits []

Comment: @user6259926 currently I do not have windows..When I will reach home I will try to find a solution for windows

Comment: thanks for all your help. got it to work. windows .txt file seemed to be the issue copied the contents to a non txt file and also tweaked the regex so that it will dot after the \n and before the mtu  because there is a space there -> '(tengig.*(?:\n).mtu.*?(?:\n).carrier-delay[^\n]+)'

Comment: @user6259926 good that it worked..there is always some issue with copying of file because of different ways in which OS treats same file